# How can I write multiple lines to a textbox using python win32?

Tags: python, c, winapi, textbox

I have a C program that has a textbox component. I want to have a python GUI write text to this text box. Currently, I can write to the textbox `HWND` using:

```
def winFunc(hwnd, lparam):
    s = win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)
    if s == "":
        win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, win32con.WM_SETTEXT, 0, lparam)

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow("Graph Program", None)
win32gui.EnumChildWindows(hwnd, winFunc, text)
```

This code will write text to the textbox but it cannot append text on a newline to the textbox. Is it possible to read in the text that is currently in the textbox or is it possible to add text to a textbox? I am new to using the windows API. Also, Is it possible to write text as a different color? The text box class is `RICHEDIT20A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Appending text**

1. Send an [`EM_SETSEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761661%28VS.85%29.aspx) message to move the selection to the end of the rich edit control. Use `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` to find out how many characters are in the edit control.
2. Send an [`EM_REPLACESEL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761633%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) message to replace the selection. If the selection point is at the end of the control, then replacing is the same as appending.

Don't attempt to use `WM_GETTEXT` & `WM_SETTEXT` since it rapidly becomes inefficient, not to mention the fact that the formatting is not preserved.

**Formatting text**

Use the [`EM_SETCHARFORMAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774230%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to format text.  More details over at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh298393%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I still can not find a way to change the text color so that each appended line is a new color in python. I was not able to find a way to call EM_SETCHARFORMAT using python.

Comment: I was thinking win32gui.SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, format) but I also do not know how to (in python) specify a Charformat structure.

Comment: I think you may need to use ctypes structure classes to replicate `CHARFORMAT`. I would also point out that you are meant to ask one question at a time. You asked about appending text, and formatting it.

Comment: I have posted a new question to focus on color formatting.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903692/how-can-i-write-color-text-to-a-textbox-using-python-and-the-win32-apis

Comment: @gh4x Good, I think that's exactly what to do.