# How can I write color text to a textbox using python and the win32 api's?

Tags: python, winapi, colors, sendmessage

Basically I want to write colored text to a textbox window of another application using python.

The general idea is to:

```
win32gui.SendMessage( hwnd, EM_SETCHARFORMAT, SCF_SELECTION, format);
```

where format is a [CHARFORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787881(VS.85).aspx).

My problem is that EM_SETCHARFORMAT and SCF_SELECTION are not included in the win32con library (I think) and I am unsure how to create a CHARFORMAT object.

Is this possible in python?

Comment: Do you have a short app that you could post that we could use as a test bed. I think I could put together a ctypes based CHARFORMAT in short time, but I can't really test it without building an app that has a rich edit, message pump etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not own the application that has the rich edit box and I can not send it or view its source to make a smaller app. However, I checked WordPad (on windows) and I found that it uses a rich edit also. I hope this helps.

Comment: I had a go and got 99% of the way there, but can't seem to get over the final hurdle!  Grr!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that this is quite difficult to achieve. The problem is that the `EM_SETCHARFORMAT` passes a structure by reference. The `EM_SETCHARFORMAT` is not one of the common Windows messages, it's in the `WM_USER` range. The memory pointed to by `lParam` is not marshalled across the process boundary. The receiver of the message receives a pointer to memory that is only meaningful in the sender's process.

This means that your only solution will be to use `WriteProcessMemory` to write the `CHARFORMAT` buffer into a block of memory allocated in the target process.  This is all possible but quite cumbersome, especially in Python.

If I were you, I would consider an alternative solution to your problem.

Comment: Booo!! Thanks for the help though!